# Disable button click animation withouth setEnable(false)

Tags: java, android, button, onclick

I have a `LienarLayout` with a `Button` in it. I have a `OnClickListener` on both the `Button` and the `LinearLayout`. At some point I would like to disable the `Button` and pass the `onClick` event to the parent `LinearLayout`. I found out that you achieve this by setting `Button.setClickable(flase)`. Which works and the `LinearLayout` gets the click, however the `Button`'s click animation is still played. Even worse, if I click on the `LinearLayout` where the `Button` is not drawn, the Buttons click animation still plays!

If anyone knows how I can achieve what I want, I would greatly appreciate it.

P.S.: The reason I don't want to use `Button.setEnabled(false)` is because I don't want the button to look disabled. I would also like to be able to enable / disable button's clickable state on demand. So basically I would like the button to be active sometimes and then other times for the click to pass through to the LinearLayout.

The code - xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="button"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The code - java:

```
Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
btn.setClickable(false);
```

Before click:
[image: Before click]
During click on LinearLayout:
[image: During click on LinearLayout]

Comment: you can use `button.setOnClickListener(null)` when you don't want to achieve click and can set listener anytime in future according to the requirement.

Comment: I can suggest few workaround options: 1) use touch listener instead of click. 2) set a static image background to the button (withpout the states drawable), 3) place some clickable view over the button, so it will catch all clicks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply give `background` color so as the animation won't happen.

```
android:background="@android:color/white"
```

When you want clickable animation back, use this

```
TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground, outValue, true);
yourButton.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
```

This will solve this issue.

Comment: How would I restore it back to normal once I make it clickable again?